# Inner join table in case condition MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, case, inner-join

I have a scenario in which I want to inner join a table when it meets a condition. I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
CASE 
    WHEN some_condition THEN INNER JOIN table_2 ON some_other_condition
END
```

I have gone through many references and previous StackOverflow answers. But, those don't meet my requirement.

**EDIT :**

```
Table 1
id  |  name  |  price
1   |  aaa   |  111
2   |  bbb   |  222
____________________

Table 2
id  |  discountedPrice  |  orgId
1  |   100          |        org1
2  |   200          |        org2
```

Added tables. For some organizations, I want to show the only price. But, some users have a price discount. So, want to show the discount to few users. So, I want to inner join conditionally.

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Comment: Use dynamic sql for such queries

Comment: @fa06, what data you want.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed, I don't want to use dynamic query as it is prone to sql injection.

Comment: Another option is ` UNION` clause but I can prefer this after knowing what are your exact output requirements with sample data.

Comment: data for your tables and your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06, I have added mock table data.

Comment: @SaiUnique, based on your sample data for which organization you want to show original price and for which discounted price?

Comment: @fa06, for a particular organizatoin `org0`, I don't want to inner join table-2. Means, for other organisatons I want to inner-join based onn the `orgId` of the second table.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`.  You are not clear on what you want to actually do, but something like this:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.discounted_price, ?) as discounted_price
from table_1 t1 left join
     table_2 t2
     on <join conditions> and
        <some condition>;
```

Comment: I don't want to join a table at all on some condition. But in your solution, you are joining all the time using some condition which will give empty result on failure condition. Question updated. Please check once. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use IF clause to validate the condition then proceed with your `INNER JOIN` query.

*I am not sure, when your condition not matched. As a dummy, I put simply a SELECT*

Syntax

```
IF expression THEN
   statements;
ELSE
   else-statements;
END IF;
```

You can try below

```
 IF (some_condition to filter org) THEN

 SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON some_other_condition

 ELSE

 SELECT * FROM table_1 ;

END IF
```

Comment: Provide an example query to understand your answer

Comment: Is this valid syntax?

Comment: Dear friend, Ultimately I am trying to explain the ideology as per your question tone. Now i have added the syntax also.

Comment: Do not give generic answer rather than prove it with the same example

Comment: @GaganBurde Already updated my answer. Were you able to check it?

Comment: @Santhana, I am getting syntax errors. It is saying `IF` is not valid at this position.

Comment: @Santhana, `IF (@~~role~~@ = '0') THEN
 SELECT * FROM subservicetype sstype
 INNER JOIN orgspecialprice osp ON osp.subserviceTypeIdFk = sstype.subserviceTypeId AND osp.organisationIdFk = 'asdf'
ELSE 
 SELECT * FROM subservicetype
END IF;` This is how I used.